# parsing owl file

Tags: java

I have an OWL file and i want to extract the classes present in the owl file.Can anyone provide a sample program in java how to do this. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should take a look at [OWL API](http://owlapi.sourceforge.net/) which has been designed to work with OWL files (OWL 2).

<s>Since OWL is XML,</s> If your OWL file is expressed in XML, your other option is to parse it using an XML-parsing library.

Comment: Owl could be expressed in an xml format.(owl is xml is extremely misleading) Parsing owl in using xml parser is to ignore all the semantic information in the model.

Comment: @doc_180 not necessarily. Parsing an OWL file that is formatted as XML, using an XML parser is fine as long as you know what you're looking for. The OP only wanted to extract the classes present in the file. You're right that OWL isn't XML.

Comment: Since the problem statement is rectified, I am reverting back my down vote.